# TypeError at /recomm/ __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'movie'

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error while getting the movies from the function it shows mistakes movies got an unexpected 
     keyword argument movie

```
File "E:\FinalYearProject\movierecommendationsystem\myapps\views.py" in recomm
 106.   return HttpResponse('recommend.html', movie=movie, r=r, t='s')           
 Exception Type: TypeError at /recomm/
 Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'movie'

def create_sim():
    data = pd.read_csv('./datasets/movies.csv')
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(data['combined_features'])
    sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix)
    return data, sim

def rcmd(m):
    m = m.lower()
    try:
        data.head()
        sim.shape
    except:
        data, sim = create_sim()
    if m not in data['title'].unique():
        return('Not found.')
    else:
        i = data.loc[data['title'] == m].index[0]
        lst = list(enumerate(sim[i]))
        lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        lst = lst[1:11]
        l = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            a = lst[i][0]
            l.append(data['title'][a])
        return l
```

And my recommend.html is

```
{% if t == 's' %}
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <h3 style="color:rgb(0, 102, 255)">Sorry! This movie is not in our database.</h3>
    <h3 style="color:rgb(0, 102, 255)">Please check if you spelled it correct.</h3>
    <h3 style="color:rgb(0, 102, 255)">Or try with another movie.</h3>
</div>

{% else %}
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <h1 style="color:rgb(0, 102, 255)">"{{movie}}" is a great choice.</h1>
    <h3 style="color:rgb(0, 102, 255)">Here are some more like this</h3>
</div>

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {% for m in r %}
    <li class="list-group-item" style="color:rgb(0, 179, 0)"><strong>{{m}}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

When I search [any movies]  such as 'Avatar' it always shows ['anymovies']= Avatar is a great choice and show Not found from   def  rcmd function

Answer (score 1):

`HttpResponse` won't automagically render a template.
You'll want `render()` instead.

**EDIT:** Fixed those unbound variales and simplified the code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def recomm(request):
    movie = request.GET.get('movie')
    r = t = None
    if movie:
        r = recommendation(movie)
        t = ('s' if isinstance(r, list) else 't')
    return render(request, 'recommend.html', {
        'movie': movie,
        'r': r,
        't': t,
    })
```

Comment: I am using it in django not in flask how to render it even using render it shows error

Comment: Why do you have Flask in your tags then?

Comment: Added the equivalent Django syntax.

Comment: Thanks for solving the error but its not displaying any result data

Comment: @bishrut You'll have to add the full recommend.html template to help with debugging that.

Comment: but now it shows  error local variable 'movie' referenced before assignment even I have make recommend.html templates

Comment: @bishrut Yes, since not all branches in your code actually declared `movie`... See my edit, I added a robust version of your view function.

Comment: yes thanks your answer works but it shows nothing I have edited the post please you could help I am new this  django and ML

Comment: Try `print(movie, r, t)` before the `render()` invocation, then look at the console you're running `runserver` in. If those show some output, the error is in your template; otherwise it's in your ML code.

Comment: Well, your recommendation is `Not Found` then :)

Comment: Look, you'll have to debug that yourself. You're using a bare `except:`, for instance; you can never know if something goes wrong there.

Comment: now i have solve the problem of Ai  part and the recommended movies are shown in console but I stuck in my recommend.html and how to render using your get method